# cmake ADD_EXECUTABLE cannot set "../bin/xxx"

Tags: cmake

I run cmake in the path "${PROJECT_NAME}/build", and I want generate the executable file in "${PROJECT_NAME}/bin" not "${PROJECT_NAME}/build".

When I used "ADD_EXECUTABLE(../bin/${PROJECT_NAME} ${sources})", I got the error:
The target name "../bin/xxxx" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior.

Then I changed to "ADD_EXECUTABLE(${PROJECT_NAME} ${sources})", it passed, but it's generated in "${PROJECT_NAME}/build".

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_executable`, as well as `add_library` and other functions like `target_include_directories` expect a name of a target, not path.

To change location of output files you're suggested to change a few properties **for each target**

```
set_target_properties(my_target PROPERTIES
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../bin"
        PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../bin"
```

There are also a few properties to control where libraries and archives go to: `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` and `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`, you can set them to something too

Answer (score 0):

Try using custom command post build to copy the executable:

```
set(COPY_TO_PATH ${PROJECT_NAME}/bin)
add_custom_command(TARGET xxx POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                       ${PROJECT_NAME}/bin/xxx
                       ${COPY_TO_PATH})
```